# Vue component submits data twice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, async-await, try-catch

My data model has a Site (coordinates) to which an Observation can be keyed. When a user submits a Site and Observation(s), these go into IndexedDB using localForage, and the Outbox component can post to server when user is online.

The problem is that a Site is posted correctly, but an Observation is posted twice. I am inexperienced with async/await and try/catch. Here's the submit button:

```
<b-button
      v-if="this.obsOutbox.length"
      @click.once="syncDb"
      variant="dark"
      size="lg"
      class="m-5 w-75"
    >
      <b-spinner small v-if="syncing"></b-spinner>&nbsp;&nbsp;Upload data
    </b-button>
```

And here is the script for the component:

```
<script>
import api from '@/api.js'
import GlobalComponents from '@/globalComponents.js'
import { contextMixin } from '@/mixins/context.js'
import localForageMixin from '@/mixins/localForageMixin.js'
import onlineMixin from '@/mixins/onlineMixin.js'

export default {
  title: 'Outbox',
  name: 'Outbox',
  mixins: [contextMixin, localForageMixin, onlineMixin],
  components: {
    ...GlobalComponents
  },
  data() {
    return {
      error: null,
      // online: null,
      syncing: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    editObs(obs) {
      // opens ObsEdit with obs object (as prop?)
    },
    addObs(site) {
      // opens ObsNew with site as prop?
    },
    siteDelete(index) {
      confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this site?')
      this.siteTable.removeItem(this.siteOutbox[index][0])
      this.siteOutbox.splice(index, 1) // 2nd parameter means remove one item only
      this.siteLength -= 1
      localStorage.removeItem('site')
    },
    obsDelete(index) {
      confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this observation?')
      this.obsTable.removeItem(this.obsOutbox[index][0])
      this.obsOutbox.splice(index, 1) // 2nd parameter means remove one item only
      this.obsLength -= 1
    },
    formatObsTable(obj) {
      let t = '<table>'
      t +=
        '<tr><td colspan="2" class="head"><b>' +
        obj.questionName +
        ' on <em>' +
        obj.siteName +
        '</em></span></b></td></tr>'
      for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        // don't display these
        const skips = [
          'project',
          'observer',
          'question',
          'questionName',
          'siteName'
        ]
        if (!skips.includes(k)) {
          t += '<tr><td><b>' + k + ': </b></td>'
          if (k == 'image') {
            //THIS NEEDS TO BE MORE ROBUST
            t +=
              '<td><img src="' +
              URL.createObjectURL(v) +
              '" width="300px" / ></td></tr>'
            URL.revokeObjectURL(v)
          } else {
            t += '<td>' + v + '</td></tr>'
          }
        }
      }
      t += '</table>'
      return t
    },
    // checkNetwork() {
    //   if (navigator.onLine) {
    //     this.online = true
    //   } else {
    //     this.online = false
    //   }
    // },
    async syncDb() {
      // await checkNetwork()
      // if (!this.online) {
      //   alert('oops, you do not have network connection!')
      //   return
      // }
      this.syncing = true
      if (this.siteOutbox.length) {
        // loop thru sites in Outbox
        try {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.siteOutbox.length; i++) {
            const site = this.siteOutbox[i][1]
            const siteKey = this.siteOutbox[i][0]
            const response = await api.post('sites/new', site)
            site.id = response.data.id
            localStorage.setItem('site', JSON.stringify(site)) //updates localStorage with site.id
            await this.postObs(site) // async, posts all obs matching site name
            if (response.status === 201) {
              await this.siteTable.removeItem(siteKey)
            } else {
              alert('ERROR!')
            }
          }
        } catch (e) {
          this.error = e
        }
      }
      await this.cleanupObs()
      this.syncing = false
    },
    async postObs(site) {
      //gives obs a site.id and posts them
      for (var ob = 0; ob < this.obsOutbox.length; ob++) {
        try {
          const obsKey = this.obsOutbox[ob][0]
          const obs = this.obsOutbox[ob][1]
          const obsSiteName = obsKey.split('_')[0]
          delete obs.questionName //only needed for Outbox display
          delete obs.siteName //only needed for Outbox display
          if (obsSiteName === site.name) {
            obs.site = site.id // replace site name with site.id
            var fd = new FormData()
            for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(obs)) {
              fd.append(k, v)
            }
            const response = await api.post('/obs-new/', fd)
            if (response.status === 201) {
              this.obsTable.removeItem(obsKey)
              console.log(this.obsTable)
            }
          }
        } catch (e) {
          this.error += e.message
        }
        console.log('site obs should be posted now')
        return
      }
    },
    async cleanupObs() {
      // this posts observations that are keyed to existing sites
      if (this.obsOutbox.length) {
        for (var m = 0; m < this.obsOutbox.length; m++) {
          try {
            // post the obs that have site.ids
            const obsKey = this.obsOutbox[m][0]
            const obs = this.obsOutbox[m][1]
            const fd = new FormData()
            for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(obs)) {
              fd.append(k, v)
            }
            const response = await api.post('/obs-new/', fd)
            if (response.status === 201) {
              this.obsTable.removeItem(obsKey)
            }
            // api.post('/obs-new/', fd).then(response => {
            //   if (response.status === 201) {
            //     this.obsTable.removeItem(obsKey)
            //   } else {
            //     this.error = 'something went wrong in posting this observation'
            //   }
            // })
          } catch (e) {
            this.error = e
          }
        }
        // refreshes the Outbox page if successful
        if (!this.error) {
          this.$router.go()
        }
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.checkNetwork()
    if (localStorage.site) {
      this.site = JSON.parse(localStorage.site)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the question as your explanation is not syncing with the code example you provided. Can you please explain which part of the code is triggering twice?

Comment: The syncDb() function, which also runs the postObs() and cleanupObs() functions, ends up posting an Observation twice.

Answer (score 0):

Removing .once from the @click and then check.

If it doesn't work, check the loop section in the syncDb method. It may run twice.